# Choose only the first input file from input

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm making an Automator App that will run an AppleScript. The app will be used for running a Terminal script on a file which the input receives - both by launching the app or by dropping a file on the app's icon. When launching the app, user can select a file manually. However, when user drops multiple files onto the app, I want it to choose only the first file of those files, because the script used later can only work with one single file at a time.

Below is the code I have until now. When one or multiple files are dropped on the app, I get an error: "Can't get item 1 of 1."

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}
    if input is {} then
        set inputFile1 to (POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "Please select a file to process:"))
    end if
    
    if input is not {} then
        set inputFile1 to {}
        repeat with i from 1 to count input
            set end of inputFile1 to quoted form of (POSIX path of (first item of i))
        end repeat
    end if
    
    tell application "Terminal"
        if not (exists window 1) then reopen
        activate
        do script "xxx" & inputFile1 in window 1
    end tell
end run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is the minimum coding to achieve the goal presented in the OP, that is to only act on the first *file* dropped on the **Automator** created **AppleScript** *application* using a single **Run AppleScript** *action*:

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}
    
    if input is {} then
        set inputFile1 to ¬
            quoted form of POSIX path of ¬
            (choose file with prompt "Please select a file to process:")
    else
        set inputFile1 to quoted form of ¬
            (POSIX path of first item of input)
    end if
    
    tell application "Terminal"
        if not (exists window 1) then reopen
        activate
        do script "echo" & space & inputFile1 in window 1
    end tell
    
end run
```

- Note the use of `echo` in the `do script` *command* for testing purposes, instead of `xxx` as in the OP.

[image]

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much - I didn't know about using the "¬" sign. Of course the "xxx" was just a bad example, I am using a different script for the job. I'll look into the Error statements, thank you!

Comment: @user24, I use the _line continuation character_ `¬` to make the _code_ more readable. It can be created by pressing **⌃L**  (Option-L) in **Script Editor**, and _error handling_ can be quite useful as appropriate, so please review the links. Happy Coding!